# R cor changes variables names

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I've noticed that R changes column names when those could be arguments. For example

```
foo.df <- data.frame("for" = rnorm(100,0,1), "else"=rnorm(100,2,0.1))
foo.cor.df <- cor(foo.df)
```

The colnames in the resulting matrix are "for." and "else." suffixed with periods. Is this documented? Is there a solution other than just cleaning up the new columns names?

Comment: Those are reserved words. See `?Reserved` and `?make.names`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` and `else` are among the reserved words in R and using them as names in a data frame is not valid. See `?data.frame` and the `check.names` argument, which directs you to `?make.names`, which has:

```
Details:

     A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the
     dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot
     not followed by a number.  Names such as ‘".2way"’ are not valid,
     and neither are the reserved words.
```

noting the last line.

The appended `.` is added to make the names valid.